# TBB: How to get the current task arena?

Tags: c++, tbb

I have a small scheduler observer class

```
namespace
{
    class TestObserver : public tbb::task_scheduler_observer
    {
    public:
        TestObserver(tbb::task_arena& a) : tbb::task_scheduler_observer(a)
        {
            observe(true); // activate the observer
        }

        /*override*/ void on_scheduler_entry(bool worker)
        {
            // Do something here
            std::cout << "on_scheduler_entry: " << tbb::task_arena::current_thread_index() << std::endl;
        }

        /*override*/ void on_scheduler_exit(bool worker) 
        { 
            std::cout << "on_scheduler_exit: " << tbb::task_arena::current_thread_index() << std::endl;
        }
    };
}
```

And I'd like to initialize it with the current task arena. In my main code, I initialize TBB thusly:

```
unsigned int numThreads = num_threads;
if (numThreads < 1) numThreads = tbb::task_scheduler_init::automatic;

tbb::task_scheduler_init init(numThreads);

TestObserver obs(...); // <-- fail!
```

I'd like to initialize the observer with the current task arena. While I don't explicitly initialize one, TBB should do do automatically, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `tbb::task_scheduler_init` class; it's already [deprecated](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/tbb-revamp) and will eventually be removed. If you need to limit the number of threads globally, use `tbb::global_control` instead; if you want to limit concurrency for a given job, use `tbb::task_arena`. In the latter case, you will also have no problem with attaching an observer to it.

To create an observer for the current task arena, use `tbb::task_scheduler_observer(true)`. The boolean argument is used to distinguish such "local" observer from a "global" one, i.e. not tied to any specific arena (the "global" semantics was the initial one for TBB observers, and it has taken the default constructor).

You might also create a `task_arena` object attached to the current arena, and use that for initializing your observer as well as for job submission. For that, construct or initialize the arena with the special argument: `tbb::task_arena(tbb::task_arena::attach())`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not constructed an explicit `tbb::task_arena`, there is no mechanism I am aware of to retrieve a reference to it, and the default constructor of `tbb::task_scheduler_observer` will be internally mapped to the arena that is created implicitly. The constructor which takes a reference to a `tbb::task_arena` is intended for use with user-created arenas.

Comment: Actually, you can create/initialize a `task_arena` "attached" to the current arena. Also, the default ctor of `task_scheduler_observer` creates a so-called "global" observer, not tied to any specific arena.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov The documentation [here](https://spec.oneapi.com/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/task_scheduler/task_arena/task_scheduler_observer_cls.html) says that the default constructor creates a observer to the owner thread's arena. On using arguments true or false gives a no matching constructor error. Please share if there is something that I am missing here.